# Downloaded Eclipse and also downloaded Java SE Development Kit 7 but cannot get a new project in Eclipse to work?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse and it wouldn't open at all, then I went and downloaded Java SE Development Kit 7 and now Eclipse opens but I still cant get a new project to open where I can mess around with some code. Is it because I have them downloaded into two different locations? I have Eclipse downloaded in:

> OS(C):/Program Files(x86)/Eclipse on my laptop and I downloaded the
>   Java SE Development Kit 7 to OS(C):/Program Files/Java. Any help would
>   be much appreciated.

Comment: File --> New --> Java Project

Comment: What do you mean by "I still can't get a new project to open"? What have you tried? We need more information in order to help you.

Comment: Have you set the path and classpath ??

Answer (score 0):

Open the Java > Installed JREs preference page. Check the box on the line for the JRE that you want to assign as the default JRE in your workbench. If the JRE you want to assign as the default does not appear in the list, you must add it. Click OK.

and then if you find the right jre at place,then close the eclipse welcome page.
Then go the File option at top left corner then new and then select Java Project and it should work.

```
            File>>New>>Java Project
```

Comment: @BronzeThunderBeard  If you find any answer helpful or had contributed to solve your question try voting it up and if the answer help your overcome your coding errors then accept it,it will help others to solve same errors or problems..